# How catch and handle riderect in Ktor on Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, ktor

I'm new to programming. And I had a problem. How to intercept redirects on the client side? I'm currently learning Ktor, but all I can think of is using cURL + wscat.

All I could think of was to manually send an http request to the endpoint with a redirect via curl in the terminal, copy the link and follow it via wscat in the same terminal.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can intercept redirects using a custom plugin that adds a handler to the `Send` hook. Here is an example:

```
val plugin = createClientPlugin("redirect interceptor") {
    on(Send) { request ->
        val call = proceed(request)
        println("Redirect: ${call.response.headers["Location"]}")
        call
    }
}
fun main(): Unit = runBlocking {
    val client = HttpClient(CIO) {
        install(plugin)
    }

    client.get("https://httpbin.org/status/301")
}
```

Also, you can disable automatic redirects by assigning the `false` value to the `followRedirects` configuration property:

```
val client = HttpClient(CIO) {
    followRedirects = false
}
```